# Printing min and max function from input of a list

Tags: python, function, append, max, min

Every time I run the code I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

So my question is: How do I print/use the min and max function at the end? So if someone let's say types 5,7,10, and -1. How do I let the user know that the highest score is 10 and the lowest score would be 5? (And then I guess organizing it from highest numbers to lowest.)

```
def fillList():

    myList = []

    return myList

studentNumber = 0

myList = []

testScore = int(input ("Please enter a test score "))

while testScore > -1:

      # myList = fillList()

      myList.append (testScore)

      studentNumber += 1

      testScore = int(input ("Please enter a test score "))

print ("")   
print ("{:s}     {:<5d}".format("Number of students", studentNumber))
print ("")
print ("{:s}           ".format("Highest Score"))
print ("")
high = max(testScore)
print ("Lowest score")
print ("")
print ("Average score")
print ("")
print ("Scores, from highest to lowest")
print ("")
```

Comment: As a side note, it's usually considered more Pythonic to do a `while True:`, do the `input` only once (at the top of the loop) instead of twice (before the loop and at the bottom), and use a `break` statement to break out when the user wants to quit. The problem with doing it your way is that if you ever change the `input` line, you have to remember to change it in both places—and you're virtually guaranteed to eventually forget to change one of them, leading to a painful-to-track-down bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `testScore` is an integer. What else could it be? Each time through the list, you reassign it to the next integer.

If you want to, say, append them to a list, you have to actually do that:

```
testScores = []
while testScore > -1:
    testScores.append(testScore)
    # rest of your code
```

And now it's easy:

```
high = max(testScores)
```

And, in fact, you *are* doing that in the edited version of your code: `myList` has all of the `testScore` values in it. So, just use it:

```
high = max(myList)
```

But really, if you think about it, it's just as easy to keep a "running max" as you go along:

```
high = testScore
while testScore > -1:
    if testScore > high:
        high = testScore
    # rest of your code
```

You will get different behavior in the case where the user never enters any test scores (the first one will raise a `TypeError` about asking for the max of an empty list, the second will give you -1), but either of those is easy to change once you decide what you actually want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If all your scores are in a array.

```
print("The max was: ",max(array))
print("The min was: ",min(array))
```